# How to mock a List of certain type

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have controller which takes List as post body

```
User getYoungestUser (int id,@Valid @RequestBody List<User> requests)
{
    //somelogic and returns a user 
    
   return requests.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(x-> x.getAge())).get();
    
}
```

i simply want to mock

```
Mockito.when(service.getYoungestUser(anyInt(),anyList()))
    .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new User()));
```

*Instead of anyList,i want to use List of type Users like ***anyList(User.class) or any(List< User >.class)***,which are ofcourse not accepted by compiler,which STRICTLY CHECKS THE TYPE OF LIST during the mocking*

I got the following from other links, but couldn't figure out how to use this in the code.

```
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
List<User> mocked1 = mock(List.class);
```

I have tried the following three ways and none of them worked.Please suggest a way to use this

```
//throws compiling error

    Mockito.when(service.getYoungestUser(anyInt(),any(mocked1)))               
        .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new User()));


//not working as it treats first parameter is expression and 
//second param is a value and throws error after running the test
    Mockito.when(anyInt(),service.getYoungestUser(anyInt(),mocked1)))               
        .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new User()));



//wont work as eq() is used for different purpose,yet just gave a try, The mock 
//doesnt work
    Mockito.when(anyInt(),service.getYoungestUser(anyInt(),eq(mocked1))))               
        .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new User()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```java
Mockito.when(service.getYoungestUser(anyInt(), ArgumentMatchers.<List<User>>anyList()))               
    .thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new User()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Mockito.<User>anyList()` to make sure as its signature is as follows:

```
    public static <T> List<T> anyList()
```

But simply `anyList()` should also be able to infer the `User` type

Comment: Sorry this isn't working ,as you said,it is behaving like anyList() itself,but i need something that checks the type if the list is of User's
Adding as multiple comments to accomidate the spacing.

Comment: Lets say i have two  lists of classes A and B  and i convert each of them to List of C
List<A> listA=new ArrayList();
List<B>listB=new ArrayList();

code to be mocked:
 List<C> aToC=customMapper.map(listA,C.class);
 List<C> bToC=customMapper.map(listB,C.class);

Need something like this while mocking

when(customMapper.map(Mockito.<A>anyList(),eq(C.class))).thenRetrn(Collections.emptyList()); //returns empty
when(customMapper.map(Mockito.<B>anyList(),eq(C.class))).thenRetrn(Collections.singletonList(new C())); //returns single sized list

Comment: But this is not happening as Expected, Mockito.<A>anyList() is not type checking list of type A or B. so i am getting wrong results

Comment: I have attached the same question here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69735072/how-to-mock-a-list-which-strictly-checks-the-type-during-the-mock

Comment: Maybe the functionality of `Mockito.when` is not suitable for your problem. You could create a mock implementation of `getYoungestUser` that checks the type of the items in the list in runtime and returns the desired result.