# How to mock a List which strictly checks the type of list during the mock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

```
Lets say i have two  lists of classes A and B  and i convert each of them to List of C
List<A> listA=new ArrayList();
List<B>listB=new ArrayList();
```

**

```
code to be mocked:
 List<C> aToC=customMapper.map(listA,C.class);
 List<C> bToC=customMapper.map(listB,C.class);
```

**

Need something like this while mocking

```
when(customMapper.map(Mockito.<A>anyList(),eq(C.class))).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList()); //returns empty
when(customMapper.map(Mockito.<B>anyList(),eq(C.class))).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(new C())); //returns single sized list
```

But this is not happening as Expected, Mockito.anyList() is not type checking list of type A or B,both the maps are being treated without respecting the type of list.***So they are acting as anyList()***. so i am getting wrong results

Comment: In short, there is no difference between `Mockito.<A>anyList()` and `Mockito.<B>anyList()` at runtime, so there's no way for Mockito to check.

Comment: You could try matching on the size of the list rather than the type, using something like the custom matcher example shown in the documentation: https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.0.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html

Comment: Thanq.This answers my question.Will try the alternatives suggested.